# Select Query not working in NULL parameters JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am using `spring-data-jpa` here is my query

```
@Query(value = "select ea.* from employee ea where ids in (?1) and (?2 is null or country=?2) ", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Employee> findByds(List<UUID> ids,String country ,Pageable pageable );
```

I want to get list of employee by matching country only when parameter `country` is not null else I want to get all records in `iDs`

SQL Query is not working in case of null country parameter. I want my query to be like

1. When country is null `select ea.* from employee ea where ids in (?1)`
2. When country is not null `select ea.* from employee ea where ids in (?1) and country =?2`

Comment: change (?2 is null or country=?2) with (country is null or country=?2)

Comment: `(country is null or country=?2)` returning only record with `null` values

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Case when Condition 

select 
    case when 
        ea.country is null then 
            (select ea.* from employee ea where ids in (?1))
        when 
       ea.country = ?2 then 
            (select ea.* from employee ea where ids in (?1) and country =?2 )
      end
from employee ea
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want use native query?
This code works for me.

```
@Query("select p from Person p where p.id in (?1) and (?2 is null or p.country = ?2)")
List<Person> find(List<Long> ids, String country);
```

Answer (score 0):

[this is spring-data use @query and spel](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

> The latest Spring Data JPA M1 release of the Evans release train eases this pain by adding support

or

you can use `EntityManager`